# Storing array as Environment variable to noninteractive shell

Tags: bash, shell, array

There are several questions, which solve the problem, but I wanted to try the following approach:

In this question I am basically having an array as an environment variable and then trying to store the string into separate array elements.

```bsh
a=('Apple Tomato' 'Banana Carrot') bash -c \
'b=($(echo "${a}")); echo -e "${b[0]}\n"; echo "${b[1]}";'
```

### Output

```
(Apple

Tomato
```

### Desired Output:

Apple Tomato

Banana Carrot

### An observation:

Also, if the original array had double quotes inside single quotes array elements, will the quotes be preserved. For example: `a=('Apple "Tomato"' 'Banana "Carrot"')`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Environment variables are simple key-value pairs of strings. An array can not be an environment variable.

However, you may pass the values of your `a` array to your `bash -c` script:

```bsh
bash -c 'printf "%s\n" "$@"' bash "${a[@]}"
```

or, if you want to call the array `b` in the script:

```bsh
bash -c 'b=( "$@" ); printf "%s\n" "${b[@]}"' bash "${a[@]}"
```

In both of these cases, the elements of array `a` are passed on the command line of the script.  This means that they will show up in `"$@"` (in `"$1"`, `"$2"`, etc.) inside your `bash -c` script.

What's happening in your question is that the command

```bsh
a=('Apple Tomato' 'Banana Carrot') bash -c '...'
```

sets the variable `a` to the string `(Apple Tomato Banana Carrot)`. This is the value of the environment variable `a` in the `bash -c` script:

```
$ a=('Apple Tomato' 'Banana Carrot') bash -c 'printf "%s\n" "$a"'
(Apple Tomato Banana Carrot)
```

---

If you *really* needed to pass the data as an environment variable, you may do so by deciding on a delimiter and then flattening your array into a single string.

For example, using `:`

```bsh
IFS=:
b="${a[*]}" bash -c 'set -f; IFS=:; a=( $b ); printf "%s\n" "${a[@]}"'
```

This constructs the string `Apple Tomato:Banana Carrot` and creates the environment variable `b` with this string as its value for the `bash -c` script.

That script then splits `b` on `:` again, and assigns the split up words to its own `a` array.

I need to use `set -f` in the script to avoid invoking filename globbing on the split up words when using `$b` unquoted.

You then also want to restore the original value of `IFS` in both the `bash -c` and the parent shell (you may want store the old value in a variable to make this easier). You may also want to enable filename globbing again in the `bash -c` script, with `set +f`.

```bsh
ifs=$IFS; IFS=:
b="${a[*]}" bash -c 'set -f; ifs=$IFS; IFS=:; a=( $b ); IFS=$ifs; unset ifs; set +f; printf "%s\n" "${a[@]}"'
IFS=$ifs; unset ifs
```

Comment: I am completely unfamiliar with this construct `bash "${a[@]}"`. I read your explanation, but is it like invoking a subshell and then doing variable expansion? Without invoking a subshell just typing `"${a[@]}"`  in bash does expansion, but returns command not found. If its really invoking a subshell, then how is the variable (the expansion) gets passed to parent shell?

Comment: Actually I am having this subshell invocation with xargs as follows: `find . -name "*.md"| xargs -0 -I "{}" b="${a[*]}" bash -c 'set -f; ifs=$IFS; IFS=:; a=( $b ); IFS=$ifs; unset ifs; set +f; printf "%s\n" "${a[@]}"' _ "{}"  \;` but i am unable to put `b="${a[*]}"` after xargs. Could you please suggest change?

Comment: @Porcupine The `bash` before `"${a[@]}"` that you're quoting from my first command is what gets put into `$0` in the `bash -c` script. It's used in diagnostic messages (errors) that this shell may produce.  Without the `bash` string there, the  first element of `a` would be put into `$0` and would not be part of `"$@"`.

Comment: So it can be anything like `_`

Comment: @Porcupine I would let it be `bash`, as it's used in error messages, as I mentioned.

Comment: @Porcupine You never said anything about `find` in your question.  I would do `find . -name '*.md' -exec bash -c 'for name; do echo "$name"; done' bash {} +`.  There is no need for passing arrays or using `xargs`.

Comment: @Porcupine See also https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/321697

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/120205/discussion-between-porcupine-and-kusalananda).