# Storing array as Environment variable to noninteractive shell with xargs

Tags: bash, find, variable, xargs, array

This is in continuation of [Storing array as Environment variable to non-interactive shell - Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/636541/storing-array-as-environment-variable-to-noninteractive-shell/636560?noredirect=1#comment1192538_636560). [Kusalananda](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/116858/kusalananda), asked me to ask another question.

---

I want to find all markdown files that contain a particular regex match, and then sort the output with the files (that contain the most search term) in increasing order.

```
GREP(){
export Regex
xargs -0 -I "{}" bash -c 'grep "${GrepOption[@]}" --only-matching --with-filename --extended-regexp --regexp="${Regex}" "${1}" 2> /dev/null | wc -l | xargs printf "${1}:%s\n" ' _ "{}" \;
}

find . -name "*.md" -print0 | GREP | grep -v ':0$' | sort -n -r -k2 -t:
```

The user inputs "${Regex}". Here GrepOptions are array of options that depends on the user input. For example GrepOptions can be `GrepOptions=("--ignore-case")` or it can be some other array of grep options.

But I am unable to have the array `GrepOptions` be available in the subshell environment.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Why does `grepOptions` need to be an array? Doesn't the problem go away if you just use `GrepOptions="--ignore-case --something-else"` and then run `bash -c 'grep $grepOptions`? Do you control the values that can be stored there?

Comment: Because sometimes there might not be any grepOptions. And then  that will result in this  `grep ""`

Comment: Yes, exactly. So? That isn't a problem, and even if it were, you would have exactly the same problem if using an array.

Comment: Your suggestion: `/bin/grep: unrecognized option '--with-filename --line-number'`

Comment: Yes, you quoted the variable. This is one of the very rare cases where you should not quote (assuming you control the variable's contents).

Comment: But, in a general case a solution with quoting is better.

Comment: I hope it's not just a simple typo of `GrepOptions` (in the text) versus `GrepOption` (in the code)?

Comment: I see that you export Regex, but I don't see an export of GrepOption(s); is it exported?

Comment: @JeffSchaller It's an array. Can't be an environment variable.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you want to use `GrepOptions`, an array, as an environment variable in your code. You can't do that since arrays can't be exported.

Instead, you will have to pass the options in to you `bash -c` script along with the pathname that you want to run `grep` on.

Below, I've taken it a bit further and also pass the regular expression, and more than a single found pathname, and I'm doing this from `-exec` in `find` rather than with `xargs`.

I'm using `--` in the call of the `bash -c` script to delimit the user options from the pathnames.

```
find . -name '*.md' -type f -exec bash -c '
    re=$1; shift
    while [[ $1 != "--" ]]; do
        opts+=( "$1" )
        shift
    done; shift

    for pathname do
        printf "%s:" "$pathname"
        grep -o -E -e "$re" "${opts[@]}" -- "$pathname" |
        wc -l | tr -d "[:blank:]"
    done | grep -v ":0$"' bash "$user_regex" "${user_options[@]}" -- {} + |
sort -t : -k2,2n
```

This find all regular files with a filename suffix of `.md` in the current directory or below. For batches of such files, a `bash` script is executed which takes a user-supplied extended regular expression (`$user_regex`), some user-supplied options for the `grep` command (`$user_options`, an array), along with the batch of pathnames.

The in-line script picks out the regular expression and the user options and then proceeds to loop over the found files, running `grep` on each and counting the number of lines that are returned.

The pathname of each file is outputted with this number at the end, after a `:` character.

Output indicating no matches are weeded out and the overall result is sorted.

Due to the way pathnames are being treated by this code, it will not support pathnames containing newlines or colons. The `user_options` array also can't contain a lone double dash.

Answer (score -1):

```
bash -c 'grep ${grepOptions+$grepOptions}  ....'
```

- grepOptions is a shell variable housing the options to grep, space separated.
- naking use of ${var+alternative} ; in case options are nonnull then use them else an e empty unquoted is used which dissolves in parsing
- It is impled that shell variables are exportable.